# google actions: google account sign in restricted to a whitelist

Tags: actions-on-google

When using google actions sdk, we can invoke the google sign in using the

```
app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'));
});
```

This triggers some standard response from the Google Actions engine that says something like: `you have been successfully ...`. What if for a particular action I would like to check the users email id (say, some `whitelist` of ids) and if found to be in them, then to accept them as a valid user of the action. Can something like this be done?

Currently, if the user is not part of the list, after the welcome message (auto by Google), I am adding a custom message that says, `Your account needs to be added to access the contents of the action`. Or something to that effect.

Any suggestions on more elegant ways to handle such a requirement? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently, if the user is not part of the list, after the welcome
>   message (auto by Google), I am adding a custom message that says, Your
>   account needs to be added to access the contents of the action. Or
>   something to that effect.

Your solution sounds like what I would do. Two other options to consider:

1. You could end the conversation after learning that the email is not in the whitelist, using the `conv.close()` method.
2. You could send a [basic card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) with a "Request Access" button linking out to a Google Form that collects names and emails to be manually added to the white list.

Comment: Thanks @Max Wiederholt. Good suggestions.